# Replacing space and hyphen with astrik

Tags: php

I have php code like this:

```
    $query = str_replace(' ', '%', $query);
    $query = str_replace(''', '%', $query);
```

I want to know is it good idea to check for space or hyphen before i go this code? Also is there a one line way to do this rather than having this in two lines?

Comment: Have you tried it? Stack's syntax highlighting doesn't seem to agree.

Comment: You can pass an array as the first argument (well, you can pass an array for both, but you only want to do it for the first). Everything in that array will replaced by the string in the second argument.

Answer (score 1):

str_replace will take an array for the "to find" chars, and optionally the "replace with" char(s) as well:

```
$newquery = str_replace(array(' ', "'"), '%', $query);
```

If you provide a single char for the "replace with" paramter, then ALL of the chars in the "to find" list will be replaced with that one char.